# The correct way to request an Elasticsearch cluster using REST http

Tags: elasticsearch

My app is requesting my Elastic instance using Http rest call. For that I use the IP of my instance directly in my Rest calls.

What should I change if I want to add Replicas? How will my app know about the IP of the replica in case the master node fails?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the client you use for making http rest calls you can configure the number of servers in cluster. For e.g for JS client

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
 hosts: [
  'https://server1:9200',
  'https://server2:9200'
  ]
});
```

Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html)

Comment: I'm not using any elastic specific client. I use REST java client (RestTemplate of Spring) using the URI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java or a JVM language, you can use the RestClient. Here is the import:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
```

If you are using Maven dependencies, here are the ones I use:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- add the x-pack jar as a dependency (optional) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are some sample methods for creating index, searching an index using the `RestClient`:

```
public Response getIndex(String indexName) throws IOException {
    return restClient.performRequest("GET", String.format("/%s", indexName));
}

public Response createIndex(String indexName, String json) throws IOException {
    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return restClient.performRequest("PUT", String.format("/%s", indexName),
            Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"), entity);
}

public Response searchIndex(String indexName, String recordType, Map<String, String> otherParameters) throws IOException {
    return restClient
            .performRequest("GET", String.format("/%s/%s/_search", indexName, recordType), otherParameters);
}
```

In order to build a RestClient instance you should use the `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder` class.